# java: how for loop work in the case of BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to take Input from the user as Big-Integer and manipulate it into  a For loop

```
BigInteger i;
for(BigInteger i=0; i<=100000; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

But it won't work

can any body help me.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: it looks so odd: it grows strangely ( i = i + i - 1 ) ... moreover it is not <= 1 at the beginning so the loop is not executed at all...

Comment: BigInteger i is getting declared twice; I'd think this wouldn't compile.

Comment: I purposedly didn't address the weirdness of your snippet (others have done that) but instead try to answer a more general question regarding `BigInteger` usage. If you can explain what you're tyring to do, I can see if there's anything we may have missed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You use these syntax instead:

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L);  // long i = 100000L;
i.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0              // i > 1
i = i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)               // i = i - 1
```

So here's an example of putting it together:

```
    for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
            bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0;
            bi = bi.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) {

        System.out.println(bi);
    }
    // prints "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"
```

Note that using `BigInteger` as a loop index is highly atypical. `long` is usually enough for this purpose.

#### API links

- [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

  - [`int compareTo(BigInteger val)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigInteger%29) from [`interface Comparable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
  - [`BigInteger subtract(BigInteger val)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#subtract%28java.math.BigInteger%29)
  - [`BigInteger add(BigInteger val)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29)
  - [`static BigInteger valueOf(long val)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29)

---

#### The `compareTo` idiom

From the documentation:

> This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `<=`). The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: (`x.compareTo(y)`***`<op>`***`0`), where ***`<op>`*** is one of the six comparison operators.

In other words, given `BigInteger x, y`, these are the comparison idioms:

```
x.compareTo(y) <  0     // x <  y
x.compareTo(y) <= 0     // x <= y
x.compareTo(y) != 0     // x != y
x.compareTo(y) == 0     // x == y
x.compareTo(y) >  0     // x >  y
x.compareTo(y) >= 0     // x >= y
```

This is not specific to `BigInteger`; this is applicable to any [`Comparable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in general.

---

#### Note on immutability

`BigInteger`, like `String`, is an immutable object. Beginners tend to make the following mistake:

```
String s = "  hello  ";
s.trim(); // doesn't "work"!!!

BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
bi.add(BigInteger.ONE); // doesn't "work"!!!
```

Since they're immutable, these methods don't mutate the objects they're invoked on, but instead return new objects, the results of those operations. Thus, the correct usage is something like:

```
s = s.trim();
bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

Comment: So this will iterate from 5 to 1. But what if I want to write the for loop which iterates from 0 to 4 containing five values. Can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, you have two variables called "i".

Second, where's the user input?

Third, i=i+i unboxes i into a primitive value, possibly overflowing it, and boxes the result in a new object (that is, if the statement even compiles, which I haven't checked).

Fourth, i=i+i can be written as i = i.multiply(BigInteger.valueof(2)).

Fifth, the loop is never run, because 100000 <= 1 is false.

Comment: There is no autoboxing/unboxing with `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger bigI = new BigInteger("10000000");
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");

    for (; bigI.compareTo(one) == 0; bigI.subtract(one)) {
       bigI = bigI.add(one);
    }
}
```

Comment: `bigI.subtract(one)` doesn't really "do" anything

Comment: yeah, sorry, it should set back the bigI to the result

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
BigInteger i;
        for(i = BigInteger.valueOf(0);i.compareTo(new BigInteger("100000")) 
            <=0;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

(or)

```
for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(0);i.compareTo(new BigInteger("100000")) 
            <=0;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Note that don't declare BigInteger twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is for running the loop in ascending order:

```
BigInteger endValue = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L);

for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(endValue) != 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
   //... your logic inside the loop
}
```

Comment: Instead of for we can use foreach